# Overriding CSS when an element is missing from the DOM

Tags: css

If an element is missing from the DOM I'd like to add margin space, and if the element is there then I'd like there to be no margin space.
in CSS I have tried the following:

A - So if the H2 title is on the page then I’d like there to be no margin top:

```
    #content > article > h2 > div > p:nth-child(1) {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
```

B - And if the H2 title is not there I’d like there to be margin top:

```
    #content > article > div p:nth-child(1) {
        margin-top: 32px;
    }
```

Is there a way to order the configuration of the CSS so that one can override the other if the H2 is missing, or vice vera?

Thanks,

Comment: Is this so that if there is not a h2 the p doesn't move up to the empty space?

Comment: If there is no title then it looks fine when a title is added then the gap between title and the first paragraph is to big. When a title is added by a user then I'd like to get rid of the gap/ margin-top.

Comment: So can't you just give you article tile a negative bottom margin? `.article_title {  margin-bottom:-15px; }`
demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tgo90nt2/3/

Comment: Yuss, you're right I can, thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer, if it help would you mind marking it as the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this with positioning

Code:

```
.article {
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  background: steelblue;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.article p {
  position: absolute;
  top:32px;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/tgo90nt2/

Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/tgo90nt2/3/

Comment: Thanks but the article needs to have a flexible height and there will be more than just one paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Brad.

```
#content > article > h2 {
    margin-top: -32px;
}

#content > article > div p:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 32px;
}
```